# How to replace all non-digit charaters in a string?

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace all non-digit charaters in the string. For instance:

```
String: 987sdf09870987=-0\\\`42
Replaced: 987**sdf**09870987**=-**0**\\\`**42
```

That's all non-digit char-sequence wrapped into `**` charaters. How can I do that with `String::replaceAll()`?

```
(?![0-9]+$).*
```

the regex doesn't match what I want. How can I do that?

Comment: `string.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")`

Comment: @SimY4 Doesn't work. What should I replace it to?

Answer (score 2):

```
(\\D+)
```

You can use this and replace by `**$1**`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/2

Comment: Do you mean `string.replaceAll("\\D+", "**")`?

Comment: Then it doesn't work. I need to wrap the char-sequence into `** **`, not just replcae it with `**`.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negated character class for a non-digit and use the 0th group back-reference to avoid overhead with capturing groups (it is minimal here, but still is):

```
String x = "987sdf09870987=-0\\\\\\`42";
x = x.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", "**$0**");
System.out.println(x);
```

See [demo on IDEONE](https://ideone.com/P4XoY3). Output: `` 987**sdf**09870987**=-**0**\\\`**42 ``.

Also, in Java regex, character classes look neater than multiple escape symbols, that is why I prefer this `[^0-9]+` pattern meaning *match 1 or more (`+`) symbols other than (because of `^`) digits from `0` to `9` (`[0-9]`)*.

A couple of words about your `(?![0-9]+$).*` regex. It consists of a negative lookahead `(?![0-9]+$)` that checks if from the current position onward there are no digits only (if there are only digits up to  the end of string, the match fails), and `.*` matching any characters but a newline. You can see example of what it is doing [here](https://regex101.com/r/qY9vN0/1). I do not think it can help you since you need to actually *match* non-numbers, not just *check* if digits are absent.